# Query XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to pull an xml node's value by referencing the value of another node.

Here is an snippet of one of my nodes

```
<document>
 <row>
  <DISTRICT>100</DISTRICT>
  <BIOS>BROWN</BIOS>
  <AREA_KM>3663.158164</AREA_KM>
  <AREA_MI>1414.347616</AREA_MI>
  <NAME>100</NAME>
  <REG>1</REG>
  <ACRES>905182</ACRES>
  <EMU_Name>Purcell</EMU_Name>
  <Shape_Leng>299746.4938</Shape_Leng>
  <Shape_Area>3663158164</Shape_Area>
  <LegalDesc>Northeast of District 151</LegalDesc>
 </row>
</document>
```

I'd like to fill in some HTML with value from the LegalDesc field based on the # in the DISTRICT field.

for example, I'd like to display the LegalDesc for `DISTRICT==100`. tempDist value comes from a form with a drop down

Something like this?

```
function dropDownAction(){
    var tempDist=document.HDForm.HuntingDistrict.value;
    var tempDesc=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DISTRICT")[tempDist].getAttribute("LegalDesc");
    document.getElementById("field2").innerHTML=tempDesc;
}
```

thank in advance

Comment: is district unique (as in only one row has district 100)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would load all the rows into an array (using district as a key); then simply get the description from the array:

```
var xmlDoc = // load doc
var elementsToLoopThru=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row");
var rowArray = new Array();

// go thru all the rows
for (var i = 0;i<elementsToLoopThru.length;i++){
    var district = "";
    var description = "No Description";
    var currRowChildren = elementsToLoopThru[i].childNodes;

    // go thru all the elements of a row and get the district and description
    for (var j = 0;j < currRowChildren.length; j++){
        if (currRowChildren[j].nodeName == "DISTRICT"){
            district = currRowChildren[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
        else if (currRowChildren[j].nodeName == "LegalDesc"){
            description = currRowChildren[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }

    // if district and description found, enter them as key value pair into array
    if (district != ""){
        rowArray[district] = description;
        alert(district + ": " + description); // DELETE ME
    }
}
```

Double check my code; I think it should work, but I am pretty rusty navigating XML

Then when you need to get value, simply access `rowArray[NAME_OF_DISTRICT]`

This should work if:

- Districts are unique
- and it DOESN'T MATTER IF DISTRICTS ARE ORDERED

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RwE9s/15/

Comment: After running the above code the rowArray remains with length 0 and never fills in.  My xml is actually 162 in length.  elementsToLoopThru is 162 in lenght while currRowChildren is only 23 in length.  Here is my xml http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6029868/HdData.xml

Comment: Fixed, I forgot that each node has a text node inside which holds the content

Comment: I'll try this again.  I am now thinking about going the way of JSON to hold my dataset.

Comment: Then you are just parsing json, it will be even easier